# How to deal with missing name attribute from Input tag when using Jsoup to login?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-scraping, jsoup

this is what I am trying to do but I don't know how to add the login button to formData hashMap

```
 private fun getData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLoginPage: ")
    try {
        val loginFormResponse=Jsoup.connect(getString(R.string.loginUrl))
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .execute()

      val document=loginFormResponse.parse()
        val cookies: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap(loginFormResponse.cookies())
        Log.d(TAG, "getData: ------------------------------${cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"]}")
        val authToken:String=cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"]!!
        val formData: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        formData["utf8"] = "e2 9c 93";
        formData["Email"] ="teacher@gmail.com"
        formData["Password"] ="tttt"
        formData["__RequestVerificationToken"] = authToken
        //Missing login button here

        val homePage = Jsoup.connect(getString(R.string.loginUrl))
            .cookies(cookies)
            .data(formData)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .execute()

        Log.d(TAG, "getData: ---------------------------------------$homePage")
    }
    catch (E:IOException){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLoginPage: ----IO EXCEPTION----${E.message}")
    }
}
```

[This is the website I am trying to use](http://elearninghub.somee.com/Home/Login) 
  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take `authToken` from `cookies`

```
val authToken:String=cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"]!!
```

but you should take it from the `input` in that `form` because there's another hidden input with different value.
So try this:

```
val authToken:String = document.select("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").first().attr("value")
```

And you don't have to add the button to submitted data.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,,How can I get the returned user from the connectionResponse? sorry it's my first time to use Jsoup

Comment: What do you mean by `returned user`? There's no username, only email and you can get it using `document.select(".user-panel .info>p").first().text()` but you already know this email anyway.

Comment: I meant the logged in user because I can't seem to make any actions inside the website

Comment: When you're logged in and you have new cookies you can make other requests using these cookies and site will recognize you as logged in. For some actions you only have to get the page without posting any parametes, for example to delete class connect to this URL: `/Teacher/DeleteClass/1013`. When you want to edit class you have to get url like: `/Teacher/EditClass/1013` but that's not enough. Then you have to submit the form by sending form parameters exacly as you did during login.

Comment: I save the new cookies using this piece of code    Common.sessionCookies= homePage.cookies() as HashMap<String?, String?> in login screen  then I use it when I try to add a new exam type but the response is IO Exception HTTP error fetching URL I don't know what I am doing wrong ..thanks I really appreciate your help